# Why is Counter.__iadd__ so much slower than Counter.update?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I experiment with `Counter.__iadd__` and `Counter.update` to accumulate 10,000 Counters and it turns out that `__iadd__` takes 1.8s to do that while `update` takes only 36ms.

I wonder why `__iadd__` take so much time. I guess it creates a new object first and copy that object to itself. But why does it do that? Isn't it inplace? I don't know why it doesn't just use the same implementation as `update`.

Here is my experimentation in IPython:

```
[ins] In [11]: def update():
          ...:     a = Counter()
          ...:     for i in range(10000):
          ...:         a.update(Counter([i]))
          ...:
          ...: %time update()
CPU times: user 36 ms, sys: 0 ns, total: 36 ms
Wall time: 33.3 ms

[nav] In [12]: def iadd():
          ...:     a = Counter()
          ...:     for i in range(10000):
          ...:         a.__iadd__(Counter([i]))
          ...:
          ...: %time iadd()
CPU times: user 1.8 s, sys: 0 ns, total: 1.8 s
Wall time: 1.8 s
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your hypothesis is incorrect. `__iadd__` does not create a new Counter.

The slowdown happens because the multiset operators in `collections.Counter` [filter out entries with nonpositive counts](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), which requires iterating over the whole counter every time:

> Several mathematical operations are provided for combining Counter objects to produce multisets (counters that have counts greater than zero). Addition and subtraction combine counters by adding or subtracting the counts of corresponding elements. Intersection and union return the minimum and maximum of corresponding counts. Each operation can accept inputs with signed counts, but **the output will exclude results with counts of zero or less**.

`update` doesn't do that.

Also, `__iadd__` is a hook used to override `+=` behavior. You should almost never call it manually; you should use `+=` (or `update`, in this case, or just `a[i] += 1`).